# Linux Mint 17.1 not working in dual monitor mode

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, linux-mint

I’m having problems getting my dual monitor setup working in my Linux Mint 17.1 setup.

There is a display app under the system menu and when I run it, it says I have two monitors (it even knows the brand of each monitor!). The problem is if I set the app up for anything other than mirrored display, one of the two monitors goes blank. I’m using a dual monitor video card. I didn’t add any drivers, just the latest Linux Mint install.

Here’s the `lspci` output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] R520 [Radeon X1800 XT]
01:00.1 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] R520 [Radeon X1800] (Secondary)
```

Comment: If anybody is looking at this, I tried hacking up a xorg.conf but it locked my screen. I had to log in from another computer to kill mdm. Whatever happened to the good ol' init 1 command? Now you gotta type in "service mdm stop" to get linux to enter text single user mode. That's progress for you. I'm ranting. Here's what I tried:

Answer (score 0):

The comments section don't allow large amounts of text. So here it is.

```
    ## This is the layout for the X server
    Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier  "Default Layout"
        Screen  0   "screen1" 0 0
        Option "Xinerama" "0"
    EndSection

    ## This defines your graphics card, there should
    ## only be ONE such section for each card.
    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "device1"
        Driver         "radeon"
        BusID          "PCI:1:0.0"
   ## Twinview lets you have one big desktop 
   ## shared between the screens
        Option     "TwinView"
   ## This is where you need to findthe names of your two monitors
   ## and edit the line below accordingly. This is what I have
   ## on my system:
        Option         "metamodes" "DP-3: 1600x900, VGA-0: 1440x900, DP-2: 1920x1080, DP-1: 2560x1024"
        Option         "TwinViewOrientation" "RightOf"
        Screen         1
   EndSection

   ## I don't think these sections do anything unless you
   ## Identify the monitor somehow, they can probably be removed.
   Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "monitor1"
   EndSection
   Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "monitor2"
   EndSection

   ## This is where you define a single screen that stretches 
   ## across both moitors.
   Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "screen1"
        Device         "device1"
        Monitor        "monitor1"
        SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
        EndSubSection
   EndSection
```